# Setting model field default to shortuuid.uuid() does not generate unique values

Tags: django, django-models, django-extensions

I have a CustomUser model that I want to generate a unique shortuuid each insert. 
Not sure if I'm doing this the right way because I'm running into non-unique uuids with consecutive inserts. Or am I supposed to override the create method and generate the shortuuid from there?

```
from django_extensions.db.fields import ShortUUIDField
import shortuuid

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, blank=False, editable=False, default=shortuuid.uuid())
```

Answer (score 0):

With a default you always need to pass the *callable*, not the result.

```
uuid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, editable=False, default=shortuuid.uuid)
```

ie without the parentheses.

`blank=False` is the default, you don't need to set it. Note also this should probably be the primary key: you should set `primary_key=True`, in which case you don't need to set `unique` or `editable`.

Comment: Passing it without the parenthesis throws TypeError: uuid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: I've managed to make it work by eliminating the default field altogether. Not sure if this is correct since there are no docs for ShortUUIDField.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, the field generates the uuid for you. There are (brief) [docs](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/field_extensions.html), which do say that it "transparently generates a UUID". Also the code itself clearly shows that it creates the value.

Comment: How do you know that the the uuid generate is unique and an Integrity error is not triggered? I know the probability are extremely low, but if it's happend?

Answer (score 0):

```
   install it this way 'pip install django-shortuuidfield', then use this instead 'from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField
    class Category(models.Model):
        cid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True, max_length=20, prefix="cat", alphabet="abcdefgh12345")
    '
```